# CPU Performance on Virtualised Windows 2000 for Oracle 8.0.5

Tags: virtualization, performance, oracle, windows-2000

Can somebody suggest any steps I can take to improve the CPU performance of an Oracle 8.0.5 database on a Virtualised Windows 2000?

**Update**

New installed OS, Windows 2000 Server Advanced SP4
Oracle 8.0.5
Vmware vSphere 4
Cpu layout: 4 Virtual Cpu’s
Memory: 4GB
Dell Poweredge T710
Disk: Local raid 10
2 x Intel Xeon X 5560 @ 2.8GHz
8 virtual cores

**Update 2**

Only 2 CPUs are being maxed out, where 4 are available. Please refer to image:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/abc7c40bac.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/abc7c40bac.png)

Comment: What virtualizer? What hardware CPU layout / Virtual server CPU layout?

Comment: Are you seeing all the cores being maxed out?

Comment: Hi Guys, I added a chart that will answer a few more questions

Comment: Actually it looks like you've got three vCPUs maxed out, not two - have you got the vmtools installed? does this need to run on 2000 not 2003/2008? same for Oracle?

Comment: Yeah, the decisions that dug us into this hole were easy to make, but unfortunately impossible dig out with.. anyway, yeah, it seems to be 3 - well spotted, but we're aiming for utilization of all 4 cores. Any idea what could be preventing that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 8.0.5 (wince).

Well one reason that you may only be using three cores is the number of concurrent sessions. A database session executes on a single CPU (ignoring parallel processing which I don't thing was around for 8.0.5, and is an edge case anyway).

If you see this when the database is idle, then that is one set of problems (and very likely related to virtualisation). Otherwise I'd start by treating as a database problem, and try to lock it down to what the workload is.

Try having a look at v$session and maybe v$sql to see what is executing. Statspack would be the main tool for investigating performance from the database end.

Comment: +1, especially for the wince.